# Center head above a capital letter in math-mode

Tags: math-mode

Does anybody know how I can center the head above the capital letter in math-mode? See the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `\hat{U}_q`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Hello @Skillmon, thank you very much! It works :) BR Marco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    $\hat{U}_q$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Miltos thank you very much! BR Marco

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer If this answers your question, then accept this answer.

Comment: In what is your answer different from @Skillmon   comment?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to not including `_{q}` in the argument of `\hat`, you may want to (a) "snug up" the `\hat{U}` and subscript `q` elements -- say, by throwing in a so-called "negative thinspace" or `\!` -- just ahead of `q` and (b) use a wider and hence more easily visible "hat symbol" via `\widehat` instead of `\hat`.

A typographic rule of thumb -- of course, we're all familiar with the saying that rules are there to be broken, though hopefully mainly by the persons who truly understand the rules... -- is to use `\hat` for lowercase letters, e.g., `\hat{x}`, and `\widehat` for uppercase letters, e.g., `\widehat{X}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\hat{U_q} \quad \hat{U}_q \quad \hat{U}_{\!q} \quad \widehat{U}_{\!q}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Though I personally prefer `\hat{U}` over `\widehat{U}` nice and informative summary of the different options! +1

Comment: @Skillmon - Thanks! You are definitely a person who understands the rules of fine math typography really well -- and hence are in a perfect position to decide which ones to apply, and which ones to ignore. :-)

Comment: Hello @Mico thank you very much! BR Marco

Comment: @Mico "You are definitely a person who understands the rules of fine math typography really well" probably not :)

Comment: I disagree; `\widehat` is often abused and this is a case. According to my taste, of course.